# Can't Send JSON request by ajax post to hubspot create contact api via chrome Extension popup.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, ajax

I am developing an extension for Chrome to update my contacts in hubspot via API.

I used `$.ajax` method in `popup.js` of Chrome extension but can't post data it gives `Error: 400`

Here is my code for `manifest.json`

```
{
  "name": "myext",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "update contact",




"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",


"defaul": "run!"
  },

  "options_ui": { 
    "page": "settings.html",
    "chrome_style": true,
    "open_in_tab": true
  },

 "content_scripts": [ {"css": [ "style.css" ] } ],
  "permissions": [ "tabs", "<all_urls>", "storage","cookies",  "http://*/*","https://*/*" ]

  }
```

And My Request in `popup.js` is:

```
var myData = '{"properties":[{ "property": "email", "value": "testinga2112pis@hubspot.com" }, {  "property": "firstname",  "value": "Adrian"  },  ] }';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data : JSON.stringify(myData),
                url: " http://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/createOrUpdate/email/harisbintari1221q@gmail.com/?hapikey=9d5ade00-6367-45be-a2c4-8fd22144aaa4",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                success: function(data){
                    alert('success');
                    console.log(data) 
                },
                error : function(error) { 
                    alert('error -->' + eval(error));
                }

            });
```

Comment: error 404 means url you are trying to hit does not exist.Double check your url first

Comment: its 400  not 404

and i also submitted data by fiddler which was successfully updated but through my code it is not happening

Answer (score 0):

A little late but for those searching on the same issue - HubSpot does not support `CORS` as a security feature, meaning that you cannot call HubSpot APIs directly from the browser using `JQuery` or other.

You might consider moving that part of your application to the server side and passing the data you that wish to save to your own endpoint before submitting it to HubSpot.

Please [read these docs](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/faq/do-hubspot-apis-support-ajax-request) and [discussion](https://integrate.hubspot.com/t/dealing-with-access-control-allow-origin-header/1257) on HubSpot.

Comment: Small addendum: The [Submit form data (AJAX) endpoint](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/submit_form_ajax) accepts CORS AJAX form submissions.